# Making small chip buttons same size

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to make a picker for symbols and im having problems with trying to make the chip buttons the same size. Width and height are all set the same. [layout-linear-cardview-chipgroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8Xhj.png)

What am I missing? I tried playing with other settings but couldnt get them to be the same.
Starts with linearLayout and then:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/symbolsChipGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chip55"
            style="@style/SymbolsChipStyle"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:maxWidth="62dp"
            android:minWidth="60dp"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            android:text="!"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            app:chipEndPadding="4dp"
            app:rippleColor="@color/orange_dark"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/SymbolsChipStyle"
            app:textEndPadding="6dp"
            app:textStartPadding="6dp" />
```

Comment: What are you using? RecyclerView? Grid? add your adapter code

Comment: Linear layout-cardview-chipgroup

Comment: here is the code

Answer (score 0):

turning off this seemed to resolve the issue

`app:ensureMinTouchTargetSize="false"`